# Xcode Other Swift Flags not recognized in code

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a Swift project, I added a unit test target to it.
my config file Constants.swift contains a struct:

```
struct Constants {
  struct Network {
    #if APITESTS
    static let serverURL = "https://www.servertest.com"
    #else
    static let serverURL = "https://www.server.com"
    #endif
  }
}
```

In my test target `Other Swift Flags` I added -DAPITESTS
Then run the unit test with CMD+U
In a log present in my test, I can see that it's "https://www.server.com" that is selected here when it should be servertest.

If I use #if DEBUG instead of APITESTS, it works.
If I try to add APITESTS within Active Compilation Conditions (just like DEBUG) it is still not recognized.

Any clear explaination?

Comment: I tried that already as you can see in the post

Comment: I made a test just now: I put the APITESTS flag in the PROJECT config > Active Compilation Conditions. and it works. If I put the flag in the unit test target, it doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define a condition in the test target, it only affects the test; the main app is built based on its usual configuration. The two easy solutions I see here are to set an environment variable or define a special test configuration in the main app and set the scheme to use that configuration for tests.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let me check that now @kevin but that seems the more logical thing to do here. I didn't know that the compilation flags were affection only the tests compilation.

Comment: This has unfortunately one big disadvantage. If you alternate between running tests and running the app and using different build configurations, Xcode performs a complete rebuild of the entire project each time. On bigger projects with longer build times this can be very time consuming.